# How do the silicon-hydrogen bonds in polydimethylsiloxane react with a H2PtCl6 catalyst

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

How does $\ce{H2PtCl6}$ react with $\ce{Si-H}$ to give $\ce{[PtCl4]2-}$?

I know $\ce{H2PtCl6 -> 2H+ + [PtCl6]2-}$ but I'm not sure what is next.

This question comes from [this laboratory assignment](http://drgregsmaterialsweb.com/Nanocomposites%20Lab.pdf) (PDF link), in which I am asked to write the redox reaction between the silicon-hydrogen bonds in polydimethylsiloxane and the metal compound $\ce{H2PtCl6}$.

I found a [source](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.687.4534) which confirms that $\ce{H2PtCl6}$ reacts with $\ce{Si-H}$ to give $\ce{[PtCl4]2-}$, but I don't understand how the $\ce{Si-H}$ interacts with the $\ce{H2PtCl6}$.

Comment: $\rm H_2PtCl_{what?}$

Comment: $\ce{H2PtCl6}$ sry typo

Comment: OK, then it simply reduces. What else do you want to know? The mechanism may be pretty complicated; it may even be unknown.

Comment: hmm i see, because I need to write the redox reaction between the silicon-hydrogen bonds in polydimethylsiloxane and the metal compound

This is the link to the information i have: http://imgur.com/cfsTdh1

and im having trouble doing it

Comment: *Are* there any Si-H bonds in PDMS? I thought there weren't; and the structure at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydimethylsiloxane) concurs. *(checks OP's imgur link)* Ah, you meant poly*methyl*siloxane, that makes more sense. *(looks again)* Or, well, no -- that figure doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Comment: Sry, this is my first time using this site and I don want to seem like im just looking for answers to my question. This is the source http://drgregsmaterialsweb.com/Nanocomposites%20Lab.pdf of my question and all the info i have is in there and im having trouble with the redox reaction question :(

Comment: @ycY This doesn't seem like it's entirely your fault -- the lab instructions / assignment seem to have been confusingly written. Please don't take offense at the community activity around your question -- we're trying to help you edit it into a condition that'll make it a good fit for the site. Thanks for working with us!